# How to find pre-requisites for any KB article

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, sccm, microsoft, windows-patching

I want to know in Config Manager database, if there is a way to know what are the prerequisites needed to install a KB article? Something like If I want to install a KB article - `KB12345`, there must be data in some table which tells me that before installing `KB12345`, `KB67890` must be installed before.

Comment: Are you creating applications/packages for them yourself?

Comment: we are creating the deployments for each KB article on our end, so somehow we have to know the pre requisites  ( if any) for that KB article to get installed

Comment: Do you need a programmatic solution? What OS are you targeting?  Windows 10 and Server 2016, for the most part, uses cumulative updates where you simply need the latest one.  There are occasions you need a servicing stack update (SSU) as a pre-requisite, though.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore- We are targeting Windows 2016/2012 servers for now. Additionally we are seeing errors where while performing update of KBArticle2 on a server, it says 'Not Applicable' where here the message is quite misleading as the KBArticle1 needs to be installed first. We see this as a hiccup because slowly we are moving towards SCCM for our patching activity